# How to get locale region with expo and android

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using Localization from expo and it works fine with iOS. But for android it looks like you can't get region.

```
import * as Localization from "expo-localization";
  const locale = Localization.region;
```

The docs say this the following. Note the available on iOS and Web which sounds like it isn't supported on android and my console.log gives me undefined on android.

> Localization.region
>
> Available on iOS and Web. Region code for your device which came from
> Region setting in Language & Region. Ex: US, NZ.

Is there another way to get this using expo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.

1 - Best I came up with is using expo-location. It requires the location permission though.

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

Location.requestPermissionsAsync().then((permission) => {
  if (permission.status !== 'granted') {
    console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
  } else {
    Location.getCurrentPositionAsync().then((pos) => {
      Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
        latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
        longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log(`Country => ${res[0].country}`);
        // e.g. Canada, United States
      });
    });
  }
});
```

2 - Another option if you're using Expo bare/ejected workflow is react-native-localize:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize

3 - Hopefully Expo fixes this properly in expo-localization

Comment: Thanks so much for this, will give it a go and see how I get on.